# Is there a database for "Who wants to be millionaire?" questions?

Tags: who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire

I'm looking for a database or any other source that has a set of past "Who wants to be millionaire" questions?.

I would prefer one that is update frequently and that also has answers to the questions. Language-wise I'm open to questions in English and/or German.

Is there any database available?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I did but couldn't find such kind of a question listed as off-topic.

Comment: It will be came out as a list question. I think for one person to post all entire questions of full 30 series would be difficult and people may came with individual half answers.

Comment: For Who Wants to Be a Millionaire? S4.E6 (August 16, 2009) Questions click here http://thetvlegion.com/who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire-s4e6-august-16-2009-questions/

Comment: @AnkitSharma That's why I'm looking for a database...

Comment: Lets see if somebody have any idea.

Answer (score 3):

There's one [here](http://who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire-question-d.software.informer.com/) by [Cat and Mouse](http://www.catandmouse.tv/), which is a company that does live studio graphics for the entertainment industry. I have not tested the database. They have many game shows to their credit.

Comment: The website linked wants to download an .exe instead of an actual dataset, and is filled with cancerous ads. Beware.